# Zend Project: Links don't work on local Server

Tags: zend-framework

im new to Zend Framework. Now i have to make some changes to an existing Zend Project. But on my local Xampp Installiation all links doesn't work.

I already set up a virtual host. Since then the Start page work correctly.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:\xampp_54_zend\htdocs\myproject\public"
    ServerName myproject
</VirtualHost>
```

But on every Link i get an error: "Link incorrect oder doesn't exist".

Edit: 404 Error

On the Live-Server everything works correctly.

What can i do to find the error and make the links working?

Comment: Can you please share URL of other links which are not working?

Comment: myproject/vorschlag/uebersicht for example

Answer (score 0):

Try using below configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName myproject
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp_54_zend/htdocs/myproject/public"
    DirectoryIndex index.htm index.html index.php
    <Directory "C:/xampp_54_zend/htdocs/myproject/public">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: DirectoryIndex index.htm index.html index.php seems to crash the start page. Without that line links still doesn't working :/

Comment: "Link incorrect oder doesn't exist" This error message is not any generalize error, this is shown by your application only. So try to find this line in your code/script and see which condition (might be some if/else) has been applied there (Try to debug in this way). Also check application.ini/config.ini of your application, there could be some settings defined, which you might need to change for your local setup.

Comment: i get that error from the browser because its in german i wrote it like that was a little stupid of me. Should just wrote that i get an 404 Error: Objekt nicht gefunden!
[...]
Error 404
myproject
Apache/2.4.7 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.22 i check the application.ini and answer after that in a few minutes

Comment: I couldn't find an application.ini in the whole project. There are 3 config.ini but there isn't something special in it

Comment: Okay, you have your .htaccess file with rewrite rules in your public folder, correct?

Comment: i made contact to the developer of this page. the .htaccess wasn't there that was the fault thanks for your help cant't wrote you up because of to low reputations sry

Comment: Okay. Happy Coding with Zend :)